# Injection token is null inside ng-content

Tags: angular

I have the 3 components listed below where I am setting an injection token inside ChildNgContentComponent via the intersectionRoot directive, and trying to retrieve it inside the ChildComponent via the intersectionObserver directive, however the injection token is null. The problem appears to be related to ng-content somehow because if I remove ng-content and just instantiate the ChildComponent directly it works.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-htnnuu)

MainComponent

```
<div>
  main component
  <app-child-ng-content>
    <app-child></app-child>
  </app-child-ng-content>
</div>
```

ChildNgContentComponent:

```
<div intersectionRoot>
  child ng-content
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

ChildComponent:

```
<div intersectionObserver>child</div>
```

injection token:

```
export const INTERSECTION_ROOT = new InjectionToken<ElementRef<Element>>('Root element for IntersectionObserver');
```

intersectionRoot directive:

```
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[intersectionRoot]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: INTERSECTION_ROOT,
      useExisting: ElementRef,
    },
  ],
})
```

intersectionObserver directive:

```
@Directive({
  standalone: true,
  selector: '[intersectionObserver]',
})
export class IntersectionObserverDirective {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(INTERSECTION_ROOT) root: ElementRef<Element> | null) {
  }
}
```

As I mentioned above, calling it directly, like so does work:

```
<div intersectionRoot>
  <app-child></app-child>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68437831/115944